# Strip characters to the left of a specific character in a pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have the following data:

```
key German
0   0:- Profile 1
1   1:- Archetype   Realist*in
2   2:- RIASEC Code:    R- Realistic
3   3:- Subline Deine Stärke? Du bleibst dir selber treu.
4   4:- Copy    Dein Erfolg basiert auf deiner praktischen Ver...
```

In the "Key" column I would like to remove the numbers and colon dash which follows. This order is always the same (from the left). So for the first row I would like to remove "0:- ", and just leave "Profile 1". I am struggling to find the correct regex expression to do what I want. Originally I tried the following:

```
df_json['key'] = df_json['key'].map(lambda x: x.strip(':- ')[1])
```

However, this approach is too restrictive since there can be multiple words in the field.

I would like to use `pd.Series.str.replace()`, but I cant figure out the correct regex expression to achieve the desired results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```py
df_json['key'] = df_json['key'].str.replace(r'^\d+:-\s*', '', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PNoTlY/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5Cd%2B%3A-%5Cs*):

[image]

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `:` - a colon
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces

Comment: Hi @Wiktor. Thank you for sharing this regex demo and for a detailed explanation. This is really helpful.

Comment: Accepting this answer because the attached resources are outstanding.

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples, please try following. Using [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function of Pandas here. Simple explanation would be, apply `replace` function of Pandas to `German` column of dataframe and then use regex `^[0-9]+:-\s+` to replace values with NULL.

```
df['German'].replace('(^[0-9]+:-\s+)','', regex=True)
```

***Explanation:***

- `^[0-9]+`: match starting digits followed by colon here.
- `:-\s+`: Match colon, followed by `-` followed by 1 or more space occurrences.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind explaining the regex expression?

Comment: @ojp, sure detailed explanation along with documentation link is added into the answer, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

What about just using [pandas.Series.str.partition](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.partition.html) instead of regular expressions:

```
df['German'] = df['German'].str.partition()[2]
```

This would split the series on the 1st space only and grab the trailing part. Alternatively to partition you could also just split:

```
df['German'] = df['German'].str.split(' ', 1).str[1]
```

If regex is a must for you, maybe use a lazy quantifier to match upto the 1st space character:

```
df['German'] = df['German'].replace('^.*? +','', regex=True)
```

Where:

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `.*?` - Any 0+ (lazy) characters other than newline upto;
- `+` - 1+ literal space characters.

Here is an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5twFT/1)

Comment: So this does work, thanks. But I wanted to understand the regex implementation since I am a bit rusty in that area.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is great for future reference

Comment: @ojp, fair enough I've edited the answer to include a regex uption.

Answer (score 2):

Extract any non white Space `\S` and Non Digits `\D` which are immediately to the left of unwanted characters

```
df['GermanFiltered']=df['German'].str.extract("((?<=^\d\:\-\s)\S+\D+)")
```